# "Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout" not available in Magento 2.2

Tags: checkout, admin, customer

Our Magento 1.8 store had the option "Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout" in the admin, so anyone could go to the checkout and login or checkout, and guests would have an account created after checkout.

Any reason why this doesn't happen in Magento 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

It is still available. Here is Magento's user guide about this - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-guest.html. You should be able to go to Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options and find the setting there.

This is the opposite situation as yours, but still provides instructions on how to find the setting - https://community.magento.com/t5/Can-Magento-do/Could-not-proceed-to-checkout-as-guest-magento-2-2-4/td-p/94008.

As mentioned in one of the answers above be sure to run the necessary commands for updating and clearing things.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento  setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento  indexer:reindex
php bin/magento  cache:flush
```

Comment: That is not the same option as "Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout". That's just the "Allow guest checkout" option.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you set "Allow guest checkout" to NO, then it would require the user to be logged in to checkout wouldn't it?

Comment: It seems like it was removed here - https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/33b4d4f5179d773bbc8c8cc280f67766ebd7e20c with a message indicating this was useless. Not sure if they intend for the Allow guest checkout option to be used to cover both needs.

Comment: Hmm, it was probably working because of the Iwd checkout extension then.